# How to implement chat functionality in iOS and asp.net

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, chat

I am working on a project where there is an ASP.Net application and iOS application. I am looking for available tool for chatting which can be integrated in iOS as a client and ASP.Net as a server.

I have gone through SignalR and XSockets. However not sure if any better option is available.

Please advice.

Comment: Since you wrote this question XSockets created a new client that now supports .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and Xamarin (Android and iOS). And they are all full duplex sockets clients. No longpolling. Let me know if you want to test the pre-release.

Comment: sure. I would like to evaluate this product. If it suits our needs, I can recommend this to the client.

Comment: Great. Send an email to uffe@xsockets.net and I will send you the pre-release package a.s.a.p